# Magento 2 Make All Zero Values into Null

Tags: magento2, grid, admin-panel

How to make all 0(zero) values in my custom grid into Null or Blank? because when I edit and I leave a field blank it automatically make column values 0 once I save it.

[image]

**here's the code of my inline edit:**

```
protected $jsonFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonFactory
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
}

public function execute()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $resultJson */
    $resultJson = $this->jsonFactory->create();
    $error = false;
    $messages = [];

    if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('isAjax')) {
        $postItems = $this->getRequest()->getParam('items', []);
        if (!count($postItems)) {
            $messages[] = __('Please correct the data sent.');
            $error = true;
        } else {
            foreach (array_keys($postItems) as $modelid) {
                /** @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Block $block */
                $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Cumbria\EventsRegistration\Model\Events')->load($modelid);
                try {
                    $model->setData(array_merge($model->getData(), $postItems[$modelid]));
                    $model->save();
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $messages[] = "[Events ID: {$modelid}]  {$e->getMessage()}";
                    $error = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $resultJson->setData([
        'messages' => $messages,
        'error' => $error
    ]);
}
```

**XML for item listing:**

```
<column name="order_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>                    
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order ID</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

Comment: I think it was due to the fact that ids in Magento are integer

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the table field displayed in your grid supports null values.
After you do that, you can just run the query `UPDATE table set field = null where field = 0`

Comment: additionally make the table column nullable true, so when there is no value inserted then default value will be NULL.